# Xcode iOS: How to reset a sound once it has played using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, audio

So I made a soundboard for the hospital I work for, it plays different respitory sounds for the RT's to listen too for furthering education and for trainees.  I can stop and start the sounds fine.  The problem Im having is when the sound is complete.  You have to tap any button twice to play the next sound.  So I am wondering how you would reset soundfiles upon completion.  I am pretty new to obj-c and my gut is telling me to implement NSTime, however I cant figure out how to do it, or if this is even what I want to do.

Thanks in advance!

```
- (IBAction)play {
    if (soundIsPlaying == YES) {
        [audioplayer release];
        soundIsPlaying = NO;
    }

    else if (soundIsPlaying == NO) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"breathe1" ofType:@"wav"];
        audioplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        audioplayer.delegate = self;
        audioplayer.volume = 1.2;
        audioplayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
        [audioplayer play];
        soundIsPlaying = YES;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AVAudioPlayer, there is a property named numberOfLoops that you can set.
Checkout the AVAudioPlayer class reference on Apple web site.

Comment: Im not using AVAudioPlayer but I will take a look at it

Comment: According to your code, you are using AVAudioPlayer and you set your numberOfLoops = 0 which meant playing only 1 time.

Comment: You know what your right I am...I have a head cold so its not helping my thought process.

Comment: Not a problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the completion of your sound file by implementing the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying delegate, see AVAudioPlayerDelegate: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html

Then you can reset/release your player in that handler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but perhaps if you change

```
audioplayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
```

to

```
audioplayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
```

so that it looped until stopped.

Comment: some of the sound files are short.  I had thought about looping until stopped however I did not want too because I want the users to know when breathing has completed.  Also this helps with pattern breathing detection, but I wont go into boring details about what the RT's want.  thanks for the feedback!